# ModX: Resource Content box not appearing when editing resource

Tags: modx, modx-evolution

I went to edit a page on my ModX Evo site and cannot access any of the content in my resource. The box 'Resource Content', that usually holds TinyMCE is not appearing at all. I have tried on multiple browsers and even another machine, but it is just not appearing.

Does anyone know how to fix this at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about Evo but on Revo I would check the resource type settings, sounds like you have it set to a web link, static resource or symlink.